# how to import image from facebook contactlist?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

i want to login facebook from my asp.net application.after that,how can i import image from facebook account and show it in asp.net gridview.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log a user into your application and recieve an active session for them then you should consult the [Facebook authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

As far as acquiring the current session's profile picture you should use the api call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture
```

To display the picture in the grid view [consult this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)